# Adding service account to members of Google shared drive

Tags: google-drive-api

I've set-up a new service account with access to the Google Drive API.  I would now like to share one of my drives with the service account user.

Existing advice suggests you can simply share the drive with the service account email address.  Unfortunately this produces the following error:

[image]

Do I need to do something to make my service account a 'google account'?

Thanks,

Karle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Google Cloud Platform -> Project -> Service Accounts -> Service Account

Check "Enable G Suite Domain-wide Delegation"

[image]

It is now possible to share this drive to the user.